# IllegalArgumentException: LinearLayoutManager is already attached to a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

> IllegalArgumentException: LinearLayoutManager is already attached to a
>   RecyclerView

I got this `Exception` when I try to set `LayoutManager` for my `RecyclerView` and it say `LinearLayoutManager is already attached`
But before I set LinearLayoutManager for my RecyclerView, I already check if my `RecyclerView` contain `LinearLayout` or not

Like the image below, you will see `RecyclerView.LayoutManager m` = null but the Exception still throw

[image]

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager m = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
if(recyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null){
      return;
}
try {
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}catch (Exception e){
      Log.e("AA", "setRecyclerViewLayoutManager: ", e);
}
```

I don't know why this happened. How can I prevent set new `LinearLayoutManager` for my `RecyclerView`?

Here is the logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LayoutManager android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@116d9b78 is already attached to a RecyclerView: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{1cbedba4 VFED.... .......D 0,0-1080,1181 #7f0d00b6 app:id/recycler_news}
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(RecyclerView.java:1087)
                                                                    at com.toong.map.utils.BindingUtils.setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(BindingUtils.java:76)
                                                                    at com.toong.map.databinding.FragmentNewsBaseBinding.executeBindings(FragmentNewsBaseBinding.java:191)
                                                                    at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:355)
                                                                    at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$6.run(ViewDataBinding.java:172)
                                                                    at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$7.doFrame(ViewDataBinding.java:238)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:765)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
```

Comment: do you have more than one RV ?

Comment: @Blackbelt no, I only have 1 `RecyclerView`

Comment: share full code

Comment: Can you share the logcat?

Comment: Where are you initializing `layoutManager` variable?

Comment: did you used app:layoutManager="" for RecyclerView in .xml file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find the solution for my problem.
The reason is my `LayoutManager` is a singleton object (because I use `Dagger` to `Inject` it). 
I set it to a `RecyclerView` then when the `View` refresh => the `RecyclerView` will refresh and I still set this `LayoutManager` for `RecyclerView` and the error will throw

=> The solution is don't create `LayoutManager` as a singleton `Object`

Comment: Is there any other way to provide it?
I don't want to create new object every time

Comment: You are an unsung hero!